# Can I do a standard restore/recover using image file backups?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

We have a database backed up with incrementally updated image file backups.  I understand the typical use case would be to switch to the copies, but would a point in time recovery using restore/recover also work?  I'm considering this route because the storage for space for the copies is slower.

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is Yes.  Here is the supporting evidence:

[oracle-base.com - Incrementally Updated Backups: Rolling Forward Image Copies Using RMAN](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/incrementally-updated-image-copy-backups#restoring-from-image-copies)